# Вернуть значение String из @IBAction func confirmPass(_ sender: UITextField) { }!

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Добрый день! Надо вернуть String из этой функции что бы другие функции увидели его! Когда применяю стандартный синтаксис -> String, ругается что надо использовать Void! Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: покажите всю подпись функции

Comment: в будущем, старайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы - приведите подпись функции и полный текст ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из функций @IBAction нельзя возвращать значения, потому что эти функции вызываются системой, таким образом (1) системе не нужны никакие значения в результате выполнения этих функций (2) если вы хотите вызывать эти функции сами, значит вы что то делаете неправильно.

Если в IBAction функции содержится какой то код, который имеет смысл вызывать их других частей программы, это все можно рефакторить таким образом:

```
@IBAction func someAction(_ sender: Any) {
    self.someActionWithReturn(sender)
}

func someActionWithReturn(_ sender: Any) -> String {
    return "123"
}
```

и если вам надо вызвать эту функцию, вызывайте `someActionWithReturn`

Comment: А как мне тогда передать в функцию someActionWithReturn значение sender.text из someAction если передать из нее ничего нельзя....

Comment: @ИгорьИванов добавил в ответ

Comment: Мне просто надо сравнить два значение из двух разных функций IBAction которые не возвращают параметры... Как быть...

Comment: сохранять их в переменных

Comment: Ну правильно. Но переменные то сохраняются внутри функций, которые не возвращают их...

Comment: @IBAction func loginField(_ sender: UITextField) {
    
    let loginText = sender.text }. Соответственно эта переменная ни где не видна, ибо не возвращена из функции.

Comment: создайте переменную инстанса для этих целей

Comment: Как это сделать? ^^ (первый раз слышу об этом! Я новичек!)

Comment: создайте отдельный вопрос